# Табы и зачеркнутый код, что это значит и что делать?

Tags: android-sdk, android

При попытке создать два `Tab` мой код зачеркивается. Что это значит и что с этим делать?

Вот код:

```
bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

Tab tab = bar.newTab();
tab.setText("tab1");
tab.setTabListener(this);
bar.addTab(tab);
```

И вот фото, на ошибку не обращайте внимания:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я помню, зачёркиваются вызовы функций, помеченных устаревшими (deprecated). Это означает, что на данный момент такой код должен работать, но лучше задуматься, найти аналогичные им современные способы и переписать его.

Comment: А какой аналог для ``Tab`` есть?

Comment: @bukashka101 `TabLayout`

Answer (score 6):

Скорее всего зачёркнутые конструкции считаются IDE как deprecated, для лучшего понимания наведите курсор на зачеркнутую строку, рядом должна появиться лампочка, в ней должно быть описание ошибки.